# Property 'profileStore' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Readonly<AppProps>'.ts

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

Eu queria pelo menos imprimir o background red que coloquei no footer.module.scss no index.tsx.
To usando essa estrutura:

[image: /components /Footer Footer.tsx package.json Footer.module.scss types.ts]

e esta retornando esse bug aqui, no index.tsx:

```
Property 'lance' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'IProps'.
```

O index.tsx:

```
import Footer from "./../components/footer"
import { IProps } from "./../components/footer/types"

function Batata() {
  return (
    <>
      {/* Configurações de head (helmet) */}
      <main>{<Footer></Footer>}</main>
    </>
  )
}

export default Batata
```

Meu Footer.tsx:

```
import React from "react"
import { IProps } from "./types"
import scss from "./Footer.module.scss"

function Footer(props: IProps) {
  return <section className={scss.container}>{props.lance}</section>
}

export default Footer
```

O package.json

```
{"main":"Footer.tsx"}
```

O types.ts:

```
  export interface IProps {
  lance: string
}
```

Comment: O correto não seria `<main><Footer lance='algo'></Footer></main>`? Você está chamando o componente sem passar as props para ele...

Comment: Obrigada, faltava isso mesmo.